# How to scrape only tweets with lat_lon (geocode) information in R

Tags: r, filter, twitter, geocode

I'm scraping tweets by using the rtweet package in R. As I'm interested in getting only tweets who bring with them the information about lat and long (geocode) about a specific location, I use the google Api and the lookup_coords function to get the coordinates of the specified location.

Usually I do like this:

```
db <-  search_tweets(q = "xxx", n= 1000, lang = "it",
                geocode = lookup_coords("Italy", apikey = apiKey)
```

and then to filter and remove tweets without lat and lon I do this way:

```
db_tweets <- lat_lng(db) 
db_tweets.geo <- db_tweets %>%
                filter(is.na(lat) == FALSE & is.na(lng) == FALSE)
```

In order to make the last step more efficient I would like to set a filter while scraping tweets with search_tweets function, so that I can get only tweets with lat long information, but I'm not sure how to do this. Do you have any suggestion?